# Warning for foreach() in PHP but still does loop

Tags: php, html

I am getting a warning inside the browser debugger, but the PHP still works. Why am I getting a warning? Thanks in advance.

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().`

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="savefile">
    <input id="uniqueID" value="ZF4446A3GZ" name="filename" type="text">
    <input name="textdata[]" type="text">
    <input name="textdata[]" type="text">
    <input name="textdata[]" type="text">
    <input value="Done!" name="submitsave" type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)){
    foreach($_POST["textdata"] as $text){
        if(!file_exists($_POST['filename'] . ".txt")){
            $file = tmpfile();
        }
        $file = fopen($_POST['filename'] . ".txt","a+");
        while(!feof($file)){
            $old = $old . fgets($file);
        }
        file_put_contents($_POST['filename'] . ".txt", trim($text).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        fclose($file);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: check this, hope this will help u...  https://www.euperia.com/development/fix-php-warning-invalid-argument-supplied-foreach/1230 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983912/warning-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because you're trying to iterate on a non-iterable variable.

Either `$_POST["textdata"]` is not set or is not an array ($_POST usually only holds scalars and arrays)

To prevent this error, you should check if `$_POST["textdata"]` is set and is an array.

```
if ( isset($_POST["textdata"]) && is_array($_POST["textdata"]) ) {
  //DO stuff
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'.

Comment: more precise `if ( isset($_POST["textdata"]) && is_array($_POST["textdata"]) ) {`